# Spring Security UI registration code table not found

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to use the Spring Security Core UI for Grails, but I am running into an issue. I get an error "registration_code" table not found. I am using 2 data sources one is not writable the other is. I guess the plugin tries to create that table but where do I specify that it needs to use a specific data source?

Comment: You might have to create the RegistrationCode.groovy domain (grab the code from the plugin source) and add `datasource 'something'` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks what I did to solve this issue is to set my writeable data source as my default